# How to bound the Hölder norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $\rho:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a function supported on a ball of radius $r$ with
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\rho(y)|dy & \lesssim & r^m \\
\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\nabla \rho(y)|dy & \lesssim & r^{m-2}.
\end{array}$$
Then for $0<\delta\leq1$, we have the holder norm
$$\|\rho\|_{L_\delta^1}=\sup_{t\in\mathbb R^n}|t|^{-\delta}\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\rho(y+t)-\rho(y)|dy\lesssim r^{m-2\delta}.$$

I think the intermediate value theorem or mean value theorem should be applied here, but I got a worse bound $r^{m-1-\delta}$. How do I get $m-2\delta$ in the exponent? Could you show the details?

Edit1: This is from page 62-63 of Ricci and Stein,  Harmonic analysis on nilpotent groups and singular integrals: II. Singular kernels supported on submanifolds. Journal of Functional Analysis. 78 (1988), 56-84.

Edit2: add one more condition on the integral on $|\rho|$. I don’t know if it’s useful here, but maybe that’s why I can’t get the bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $|t| \le r^2$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
|\rho(y+t) - \rho(y)| &= \left|\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \rho(y + st) \ \mathrm{d} s\right|\\
&= \left|\int_0^1 (\nabla\rho)(y + st) \cdot t \ \mathrm{d} s\right|\\
&\le |t| \int_0^1 |(\nabla\rho)(y + st)| \mathrm{d} s.
\end{align*}
$$
Utilizing Fubini's theorem, we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
|t|^{-\delta}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\rho(y+t) - \rho(y)| \ \mathrm{d} y &\le |t|^{1-\delta} \int_0^1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |(\nabla\rho)(y + st)| \ \mathrm{d} y \  \mathrm{d} s \\
&= |t|^{1-\delta} \int_0^1 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\nabla\rho(y)| \ \mathrm{d} y \  \mathrm{d} s \\
&\lesssim |t|^{1-\delta} r^{m-2} \le r^{m-2\delta},\\
\end{align*}
$$
where the equality follows from translation invariance of the $L^1$ norm.

Suppose now that $|t| > r^2$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
|t|^{-\delta}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\rho(y+t) - \rho(y)| \ \mathrm{d} y &\le r^{-2\delta} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\rho(y+t)|\ \mathrm{d} y + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\rho(y)|\ \mathrm{d} y\right) \\
&= 2r^{-2\delta}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\rho(y)|\ \mathrm{d} y \\
&\lesssim r^{m-2\delta}.
\end{align*}
$$
It follows that
$$
\sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}^n}|t|^{-\delta}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\rho(y+t) - \rho(y)| \ \mathrm{d} y \lesssim r^{m-2\delta} .
$$